# how to extract sub string of a filename using different types of delimiter in shell script?

Tags: unix

I'm learning shell script. Let's say abcd-2.1.1.4.jar is file name. I want to extract the version i.e. "2.1.1.4". I tried with "cut" syntax.

"abcd-2.1.1.4.jar" | cut -d'-' -f 2 return output abcd-2.1.1.4.jar I can't using different types of delimiter

Is there is any other way to achieve that.

Thank you.

Comment: Sure, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Which real commands ?

Comment: echo "abcd-2.1.1.4.jar"  | cut -d'-' -f 2 return output abcd-2.1.1.4.jar
I can't using different types of delimiter

Comment: **always** add them to your original post

Answer (score 1):

You better try with `sed`: `echo abcd-2.1.1.4 | sed 's/.*\-\([0-9\.]\+\)\.jar/\1/'`

Hoping you're using GNU sed, otherwise it might be a little different.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply... I'm learning sed. unfortunately I don't have GNU. 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/